# Analytic solution for the ODE $\frac{d y(x)}{dx}=\frac{a*y(x)^3+b}{c* y(x)^3+ d}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple, wolfram-alpha

I have an ODE $$ \frac{d y(x)}{dx}=\frac{a*y(x)^3+b}{c* y(x)^3+ d},$$ where $a,b,c,d$ are constants, and I would love to solve it analytically.

I tried Maple 15 and 17 and got
$$ y \left( x \right) =1/2\,{ \left( {\frac {a}{d}} \right) }^{1/3}+1/2\,
{3}^{1/2}{ \left( {\frac {a}{d}} \right) }^{1/3}{\it tan} \left( {\it 
RootOf} \left( 6\,{3}^{1/2}{ \left( {\frac {a}{d}} \right) }^{2/3}{
\it \_C1}\,{d}^{2}+6\,{3}^{1/2}{ \left( {\frac {a}{d}} \right) }^{2/3}
{d}^{2}x+2\,{3}^{1/2}\ln  \left( 3/2\,{ \left( {\frac {a}{d}} \right) 
}^{1/3}+1/2\,{3}^{1/2}{ \left( {\frac {a}{d}} \right) }^{1/3}{\it tan}
 \left( {\it \_Z} \right)  \right) ab-2\,{3}^{1/2}\ln  \left( 3/2\,{
 \left( {\frac {a}{d}} \right) }^{1/3}+1/2\,{3}^{1/2}{ \left( {\frac {
a}{d}} \right) }^{1/3}{\it tan} \left( {\it \_Z} \right)  \right) cd-{
3}^{1/2}\ln  \left( 3/4\,{ \left( {\frac {a}{d}} \right) }^{2/3}+3/4\,
{ \left( {\frac {a}{d}} \right) }^{2/3}{{\it tan} \left( {\it \_Z}
 \right) }^{2} \right) ab+{3}^{1/2}\ln  \left( 3/4\,{ \left( {\frac {a
}{d}} \right) }^{2/3}+3/4\,{ \left( {\frac {a}{d}} \right) }^{2/3}{{
\it tan} \left( {\it \_Z} \right) }^{2} \right) cd-3\,{3}^{1/2}ab-9\,{
\it tan} \left( {\it \_Z} \right) ab+6\,{\it \_Z}\,ab-6\,{\it \_Z}\,cd
 \right)  \right) 
 $$

I tried Wolfram|Alpha ando got this: for `DSolve[y'[x]=(a*y[x]^3 + b)/(d*y[x]^3+c), y, x]`
[image]

and this for `DSolve[y'[x]=(a*y[x]^3 + b)/(d*y[x]^3+c)]`:
[image]

And so I wonder if there is any way to solve it analytically and get $y(x)$in general form not dependent on $y(x)$? Any special function? Or any package that could solve such ODEs analytically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mathematica already discovered for you, you will always have the equation of
$$x = \int \frac{c + dy^3}{b + ay^3} dy + C.$$
Solving this integral is possible given $a,b,c,d$, but the results differ wildly depending on the constants, so no overall solution is possible. The function $y$ you are looking for is then the inverse of the integral you calculate.

Comment: that is so sad! =(

Comment: can a condition like $$y(0) = r$$ help?

Comment: You still have to solve the integral. The initial condition can help you set $C$ more easily (see edited answer), not to solve the integral or then extract $y$ which is where the problems happen.